# Accordian not working properly using object oriented javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]I'm doing `accordian` using object oriented javascript here the problem is toggle is not working when I click.As expect output is when I click display content and icon will be `+` and other child close.initially, firstchild will be `active`.

I just started learning object oriented javascript.Anything wrong with code let me know.

```js
Accordion = {
 accordionContent: '.accordion-s1 .accordion--content p',
 accordionTitle: '.accordion--title',
 init: function() {
    $(this.accordionTitle).click(this.toggleAccordion.bind(this));
 },
 toggleAccordion: function() {
     $(this.accordionContent).slideToggle();
     $(this.accordionTitle).removeClass("active");
     if($(this.accordionTitle).siblings().is(":visible")) {
         $(this.accordionTitle).siblings().slideDown();
                $(this).find('.fa.fa-times').toggleClass('plus');
         $(this.accordionTitle).addClass("active");
     }
 }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  Accordian.init();
});
```

```css
.accordion-s1 .accordion--title {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  font-weight: 300;
  transition: all .25s ease;
  background-color: #2783e8;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.accordion-s1 .accordion--title h4 { flex:1;font-weight: 600;}
.accordion-s1 .aticon-times { padding: 5px;}
.plus {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
.accordion-s1 .accordion--content {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/a2e210f715.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion-s1">
   <div class="accordion--single">
    <div class="accordion--title">
     <h4>London Style</h4>
     <span class="accordion--i">
      <i class="fa fa-times aticon-times"></i>
     </span>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion--content">
     <p>Alienum phaedrum torquatos nec eu, vis detraxit periculis ex, nihil exp eten in mei. Mei an pericula euripidis, hinc partem ei est. Eos ei nisl graecis, vixet aperiri consequat an. Eius lorem tincidunt vix at, vel pertinax sensibus id. Pericula euripidis, hinc partem ei est.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="accordion--single">
    <div class="accordion--title">
     <h4>London Style</h4>
     <span class="accordion--i">
      <i class="fa fa-times aticon-times"></i>
     </span>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion--content">
     <p>Alienum phaedrum torquatos nec eu, vis detraxit periculis ex, nihil exp eten in mei. Mei an pericula euripidis, hinc partem ei est. Eos ei nisl graecis, vixet aperiri consequat an. Eius lorem tincidunt vix at, vel pertinax sensibus id. Pericula euripidis, hinc partem ei est.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: If you fix the spelling on `Accordian` it will clear current error. Beyond that what is the question?

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks. But everywhere I'm using `Accordion` only its not about the spelling mistake.In my question, i mention what the problem once read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found couple of mistake from your given code. `$(this.accordionContent).slideToggle()` actually targeting all of the element. Also same is `$(this.accordionTitle).siblings()`.

Hello you can try following code:

```
Accordion = {
accordionContent: '.accordion-s1 .accordion--content',
accordionTitle: '.accordion--title',
init: function() {
   $(this.accordionTitle).removeClass('active').eq(0).addClass("active");
   $(this.accordionContent).slideUp().eq(0).slideDown();
   $(this.accordionTitle).click(this.toggleAccordion.bind(this));
},
toggleAccordion: function(e) {

    if($(e.currentTarget).next($(this.accordionContent)).is(":visible")) {
        return
    }

    $(this.accordionTitle).siblings().slideUp();
    $(this.accordionTitle).removeClass('active');

    $(e.currentTarget).next($(this.accordionContent)).slideDown();
    $(e.currentTarget).addClass("active");
}
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  Accordion.init();
});
```

For plus sign you need adjust in CSS and HTML title section as well.

In CSS:

```
.accordion--i .fa-times {
    display:inline-block;
}
.accordion--i .fa-plus {
    display:none;
}
.active .accordion--i .fa-times {
    display:none;
}
.active .accordion--i .fa-plus {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

In HTML you need add following change in every title in each block:

```
    <div class="accordion--title">
        <h4>London Style</h4>
        <span class="accordion--i">
            <i class="fa fa-times aticon-times"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-plus aticon-times"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm updated for adding removing plus sign based 'active' class.

Comment: @thanks instead of using slideup/down we can use slideToggle? Is it possible.

Comment: At a time will open only one section and collapse all other section?